# Select totals from database table based on month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has product quantity column and the database has multiple entries in a single month.

Date format is (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
Date          Quantity
2016-03-01    1200
2016-03-05    200 
2016-04-05    500 
2016-04-10    1000 
2016-05-05    850 
2016-05-10    50
```

So I want data as:

- March (2016-03-01 to 2016-03-31) = 1400
- April (2016-04-01 to 2016-04-30) = 1500
- May (2016-05-01 to 2016-05-31) = 900

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query and it will return the result that you want.

' date field ' is the name of the column where date is inserted and Tablename is the name of the Table.

```
   SELECT   MONTH(date field)  as  month ,  YEAR(date field) as year , SUM(quantity) as 
   quantity  FROM  Tablename  GROUP  BY  MONTH( date field )
```

Comment: This query is undesirable, because it includes non-aggregates in the `SELECT` clause which do not also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
select MONTH(Date) As dt , SUM(quantity) total from @Table1
    GROUP BY MONTH(Date)
```

Comment: SUM(quantity), SUM(Quantity)? does it matter if it's in caps or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert the `date` field into just the `year-month` format, select the [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) of the `quantity` field, and then [`GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) the `year-month` field.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m', `date`) as `ym`, SUM(`quantity`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `ym` ORDER BY `ym` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try grouping by the month and year, taking the sum of the `quantity` field as an aggregate.

```
SELECT MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date), SUM(quantity)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date)
```

If you want the fancy output with actual date ranges, that would be a bit more work to do.  Those dates may not exist in your original data set, so it could require a date table.  And handling February in a leap year could be a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query same as it is it will return what you want

```
  SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b'),' ',
  (SELECT CONCAT('(',YEAR(date),'-',LPAD(MONTH(date),2,0),'-01 - ')
  ), (SELECT concat(last_day(date),')')
   )) dates,  SUM(quantity) qty FROM DATES GROUP BY MONTH(date) ORDER BY MONTH(date)
```

Comment: Replace your field and table name with the given field and table name in the query and run again, it will run fine  because i have tested this query and it is working fine